# Update stored procedure fails with a query

Tags: delphi, stored-procedures, interbase

Database: Interbase 6.5
Connection: the same result with IBX or BDE
Program is written with delphi 7

I try to update th sp. The result "Token unknown -line xx, char yy"  Line xx and char yy points to the first variable.

Example:

```
  query.sql.add('ALTER PROCEDURE');
  query.sql.add('MYPROCEDURE (mypkey integer)');
  query.sql.add('returns (myresult integer)');
  query.sql.add('as');
  query.sql.add('declare variable helpint integer;');
  query.sql.add('BEGIN');
  query.sql.add('select count(bla)');
  query.sql.add('from mytable');
  query.sql.add('where pkey=:mypkey');
  query.sql.add('into :helpint;');    <------ here is line xx
  query.sql.add('if (helpint>0) then myresult = 1;');
  query.sql.add('suspend;');
  query.sql.add('END');
try
  query.ExecSQL;
except
  on E:Exception do
  begin
    E.Message := E.Message +#13#10+query.SQL.Text;
    raise;
end;
```

If I update the sp with ibconsole, it works.

Whats going wrong?

#### Update:

In the original code it is the decalred variable!

correction:

```
query.sql.add('into :helpint;');    <------ here is line xx
query.sql.add('if (helpint>0) then myresult = 1;');
```

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
query.ParamCheck := False;
query.Params.Clear;
query.SQL.Clear;
```

before you assign the SQL. Don't forget to revert `ParamCheck` to `True` once you're done updating DDL.

Comment: @momaich welcome to StackOverflow, if this worked for you, proceed to accept the answer, as a bonus you'll get a badge for doing that for the first time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a variable HELPINT, so you have to use HELPINT as variable, not VARIABLE on the marked line, and on the next one too.